# Word wrap a Delphi string to a certain length using commas not spaces?

Tags: regex, string, delphi, word-wrap

I am generating a comma separated list of names in a string eg

```
Mr John Blue, Miss A Green, Mr Posh Hyphenated-Surname, Mr Fred Green, Miss Helen Red, Ms Jean Yellow
```

I now want to display them in a memo box that will hold 50 characters on each line so that as many names as possible (and their trailing comma) appear on each line.
so the above should look like

```
Mr John Blue, Miss A Green,
Mr Posh Hyphenated-Surname, Mr Fred Green,
Miss Helen Red, Ms Jean Yellow
```

I've played with

```
Memo1.text := WrapText(Mystring,50)
```

but it broke lines at spaces between forename and surnames and I tried

```
Memo1.text := WrapText(MyString, slinebreak, ',' ,50)
```

to force it to break only after a comma but that broke at spaces as well as commas. Both also tended to break at a hyphen and I note from Rob Kennedy's reply to a similar question that embedded quotes cause problems with Wrap() so a name like **Mr John O'Donald** would cause problems.

I even tried rolling my own function by counting characters and looking for commas but got bogged down in multiple nested IFs  (Too embarassed to show the dreadful code for that!)

Can anyone offer any help or code showing how this can be done?

PS 
I have looked at

- 'Word wrap in TMemo at a plus (+) char'
- 'How do I split a long string into “wrapped” strings?'
- 'Find a certain word in a string, and then wrap around it'

and other similar posts but none seem to match what I am looking for.

Comment: Sorry, Typo in this post. I meant WrapText()

Comment: Where are you getting the original string containing the names from?

Comment: I have a database table containing inter ID, Title, Forename, Surname. I use that to populate the source in a dual list box using a concatenated and cleaned up name string with the ID as an integer object. Then I take the name/IDs selected by the user, process the integer IDs elsewhere, concatenate the name strings with commas into one string and display that string in a memo box on another form as confirmation. The commas are really just to make the layout look nice as the memo box needs to be wide but only about 3 lines tall and has to easily show the 3 to 6 names that are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Memo1.WordWrap:=False;`

There are many solutions, I show here just one.
But take care :
If you are using it with large amounts of data then the execution is quite slow

```
procedure TForm1.AddTextToMemo(needle,xsSrc:string);
var
xsNew:string;
mposOld,mposNew:integer;
start:byte;
begin
xsNew:=xsSrc;
repeat
  repeat
   mposOld:=mposNew;
   mposNew:=Pos(needle,xsSrc);
   if mposNew>0 then xsSrc[mposNew]:='*';
  until (mposNew > 50) OR (mposNew = 0);
  if  mposOld > 0  then begin
     if xsNew[1] = ' ' then start := 2 else start := 1;
     if mposNew = 0 then mposOld:=Length(xsNew);
     Memo1.Lines.Add(copy(xsNew,start,mposOld));
     if mposNew = 0 then exit;
     xsNew:=copy(xsNew,mposOld+1,Length(xsNew)-mposOld);
     xsSrc:=xsNew;
     mposNew:=0;
  end else xsSrc:='';
until xsSrc = '';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Memo1.Clear;
AddTextToMemo(',','Mr John Blue, Miss A Green, Mr Posh Hyphenated-Surname, '+
                  'Mr Fred Green, Miss Helen Red, Ms Jean Yellow');
end;
```

**UPDATE**

if you have a small amount of data here is fast and easy to read.

```
...
var
 Form1: TForm1;
 NameList: TStrings;

...
 NameList := TStringList.Create;
...

procedure TForm1.AddTextToMemoB(needle,xsSrc:string);
var
xsNew:string;
i:integer;
sumLen:byte;

begin
xsNew:=''; sumLen:=0;
nameList.Text:=StringReplace(xsSrc,needle,needle+#13#10,[rfReplaceAll]);
for i := 0 to nameList.Count - 1 do begin
  sumLen:=SumLen+Length(nameList[i]);
  if i < nameList.Count - 1 then begin
    if (sumLen + Length(nameList[i+1]) > 50) then begin
       if xsNew='' then xsNew:=nameList[i];
       Memo1.Lines.Add(xsNew);
       xsNew:='';
       sumLen:=0;
    end else if xsNew='' then xsNew:=nameList[i]+nameList[i+1] else   
                              xsNew:=xsNew+nameList[i+1];
  end else Memo1.Lines.Add(xsNew);
end; // for
end;
```

Comment: That did it. Quite neat as well.

Comment: @user3209752 : Glad that you like it. The test, within the 50 character is a comma, should still be tested. Should be no problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but something along the following lines ought to do the trick.

```
for LCh in S do
begin
  case LCh of
    ',' : //Comma completes a word
    begin
      LWord := LWord + LCh;
      if  (LLine <> '') and //Don't wrap if we haven't started a line
          ((Length(LLine) + Length(LWord)) > ALineLimit) then
      begin
        //Break the current line if the new word makes it too long
        AStrings.Add(LLine);
        LLine := '';
      end;
      if (LLine <> ' ') then LLine := LLine + ' '; //One space between words
      LLine := LLine + LWord;
      LWord := '';
    end;
  else
    if (LWord = '') and (LCh in [' ', #9]) then
    begin
      //Ignore whitespace at start of word.
      //We'll explicitly add one space when needed.
      //This might remove some extraneous spaces.
      //Consider it a bonus feature.
    end else
    begin
      LWord := LWord + LCh;
    end;
  end;
end;

//Add the remainder
if  (LLine <> '') and //Don't wrap if we haven't started a line
    ((Length(LLine) + Length(LWord)) > ALineLimit) then
begin
  //Break the current line if the new word makes it too long
  AStrings.Add(LLine);
  LLine := '';
end;
if (LLine <> ' ') then LLine := LLine + ' '; //One space between words
LLine := LLine + LWord;
AStrings.Add(LLine);
```

Of course you may have noted the duplication that should be moved to a sub-routine.
Tweak away to your hearts content.

Comment: Thanks, handy but this is along the same lines as the roll your own function that I was developing myself. My strings are already cleaned up to remove extra spaces and oddities like missing forename.

Comment: @user3209752 Yeah probably. You said you were struggling with too many nested if's. So I figured this might give you some ideas to simplify your code. You'll find parsers following a similar approach. A nice exmaple is `TParser` in Delphi's `Classes` unit.